# How to get linux partition info (df command) from a web app

Tags: php, ssh, cpanel, partitioning, whm

My friend has some sort of admin panel where he displays information from several servers. He is using [cPanel XML api](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cpanel%20xml%20api&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CGIQFjAE&url=https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php&ei=yp7TUI-FM6nB0QG8goFA&usg=AFQjCNFtbE5wDK40s1eqLi0tC6VaErUyjw&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ) to display several things for example the server load average, the code looks something like this:

```
include("xmlapi.php");

$conf = simplexml_load_file("servers.xml");

foreach ( $conf->server as $server ) {
    $xmlapi = new xmlapi( $server->ip );
    $xmlapi->set_debug(1);
    $xmlapi->hash_auth( $server->user, $server->accesshash);
    $loadavg = $xmlapi->loadavg();

    print $server->ip . " - " . $loadavg->one . " - " . $loadavg->five . " - " . $loadavg->fifteen;
}
```

I've been reading the [wiki](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/XmlApi) but the closer thing I found is retrieving an account disk usage. But I need the info that comes from the "df" command ran in ssh as root. **What would be the easier and safest way to do this?** Since i need to get the df command output from several servers and not from the one running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to run df as "root"? I can certainly run it as myself on my Linux machine?
(Yes, that's a question, not an answer)

Assuming you have full access to the machine, you could probably set up a useraccount "df", that is listed in sudoers with `!authenticate` attribute (so it can sudo without password), and then `ssh df@${machine} sudo df` 
You can also restrict sudo so that the df" user can only do df, and not, for example `rm -rf /` or `adduser blah`

And of course set up your ssh to use a public/private key challeng rather than using your php code to have a password in the source - if nothing else because it makes it more flexible, and you don't have to update the source if you decide to change the password.

Comment: You are right "df" shows the same as any other user, anyway I think I will end up adding a df.php to /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/ on each server and then do some mods on xmlapi.php to get the info.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there are systems where you have to be root to see the free space on (some) drives. But those systems probably wouldn't let you log that data remotely, as the reason you can't see it as a regular user is that the owner don't want you to know that...